# Customise scopes_supported in spring security authorisation server

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have following configuration for spring oauth server

```java
    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    public SecurityFilterChain authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);
        http.getConfigurer(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.class)
                .oidc(Customizer.withDefaults());   // Enable OpenID Connect 1.0
        http
                // Redirect to the login page when not authenticated from the
                // authorization endpoint
                .exceptionHandling((exceptions) -> exceptions
                        .authenticationEntryPoint(
                                new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login"))
                )

                // Accept access tokens for User Info and/or Client Registration
                .oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt);

        return http.build();
    }
```

With this configuration well-known (http://[host]/.well-known/openid-configuration) endpoint gives only `openid` for `scopes_supported`.

Is there a way to customise this to return `["openid", "email", "profile"]`

scopes_supported is hardcoded in [OidcProviderConfigurationEndpointFilter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/blob/98e3fe807a56da3236bc92b4c07f61e61a80efbc/oauth2-authorization-server/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/server/authorization/oidc/web/OidcProviderConfigurationEndpointFilter.java#L112)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if that can be done out of the box. If I remember correctly Spring security team is working on enabling more OpenId connect specific features with the future versions of Spring Security Authz Server. I am not sure if they would be implementing this out of the box (or) we have to do it ourselves.

Since `email` is just a scope, we can register this scope at authz server level for that specific client (`ClientRegistration`) & also at the client end (in `OAuth2ClientProperties.Registration`).

Once you setup this, what needs to be done is customisation of `/userinfo` endpoint. Since `/userinfo` is secured at Spring Authz server i.e that can only be accessed using Access token (which spring login client automatically accesses as soon as the authz code flow is complete), we need to customise it so that we can send email details of the logged in resource owner at this endpoint.

It can be done in this manner.

```
@Component
class UserInfoResponseCustomizer implements Function<OidcUserInfoAuthenticationContext, OidcUserInfo> {
  private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

  public UserInfoResponseCustomizer(UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
    this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
  }

  @Override
  public OidcUserInfo apply(OidcUserInfoAuthenticationContext oidcUserInfoAuthenticationContext) {
    final var authToken = ((JwtAuthenticationToken) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication());
    final var resourceOwnerUsername = authToken.getName();
    final var builder = OidcUserInfo.builder().subject(resourceOwnerUsername);
    if (authToken.getAuthorities().stream().anyMatch(authority -> authority.getAuthority().equals("SCOPE_email"))) {
      final var userWithEmail = (UserWithEmail) userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(resourceOwnerUsername);
      builder.email(userWithEmail.getEmail()); //UserWithEmail is a custom spring `UserDetails` object that contains email property
    }
    return builder.build();
  }
}
```

and link this upto Authz server

```
@Bean
@Order(1)
public SecurityFilterChain authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http, UserInfoResponseCustomizer userInfoResponseCustomizer) throws Exception {
  OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);
  http.getConfigurer(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.class)
      .oidc(customizer -> customizer.userInfoEndpoint(oidcUserInfoEndpointConfigurer -> oidcUserInfoEndpointConfigurer.userInfoMapper(userInfoResponseCustomizer)));    // Enable OpenID Connect 1.0

  http
      // Redirect to the login page when not authenticated from the
      // authorization endpoint
      .exceptionHandling((exceptions) -> exceptions.authenticationEntryPoint(new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login")))
      // Accept access tokens for User Info and/or Client Registration
      .oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt);

  return http.build();
}
```

When you are registering your client, ensure the client is allowed to request for that `email` scope

```
@Bean
public RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository() {
  RegisteredClient frontendClient = RegisteredClient.withId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
      .clientId("my-client")
      .clientSecret("{noop}my-client-secret")
      .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_BASIC)
      .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
      .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.REFRESH_TOKEN)
      .redirectUri("http://my-client.com/login/oauth2/code/my-client")
      .scope(OidcScopes.OPENID)
      .scope(OidcScopes.PROFILE)
      .scope(OidcScopes.EMAIL)
      .build();
}
```

With these changes in place on Authz server end, you should be able complete Auth code flow & hit the `/userinfo` endpoint on Authz server & access email address of the user.

Please note that with default settings in spring login module, when a client complete authz `code` flow for `openid` flow, the library automatically fetches `/userinfo` endpoint. So, you should be able access this email address at the oauth client end by accessing the claims inside this object `(OidcUser)((OAuth2LoginAuthenticationToken)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication())).getPrincipal())`.